Getting error "actions are deprecated. Please update"
I am using this config file that I got from:
https://www.photondesigner.com/articles/lambda-for-django
name: Deploy lambda to production using Chalice

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    env:
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
      AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: ${{ secrets.AWS_DEFAULT_REGION }}

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: 3.11

      - name: Install required packages
        run: pip install chalice requests

      - name: Deploy lambda to production
        run: |
          cd helloworld
          chalice deploy --stage prod

I am getting an error:
Node.js 16 actions are deprecated. Please update the following actions to use Node.js 20: actions/setup-python@v3.

Not sure which version should be used.

So go find out.

Does this answer your question? Github actions failing after upgrading to node v20

No. It does not. I tried versions 2, 3, 4 and 5 before posting this question.

Seems pretty unlikely because v5 does use Node 20: https://github.com/actions/setup-python/issues/735, https://github.com/actions/setup-python/releases/tag/v5.0.0. If you have tried one that's supposed to work and didn't, why post about one that's not supposed to work (and why try an even older one)?

You should update the checkout action to v4 and the setup-python to v4 minimum (v5 preferably) :
steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v4

  - uses: actions/setup-python@v4
    with:
      python-version: 3.11


Tried. Same error.

Can you link or copy paste the logs of the action please ?

Node.js 16 actions are deprecated. Please update the following actions to use Node.js 20: actions/setup-python@v4. For more information see: https://github.blog/changelog/2023-09-22-github-actions-transitioning-from-node-16-to-node-20/.

No I mean the logs from the runner, like this for example : https://github.com/ArnaudFlaesch/Dash-Web/actions/runs/9008511020/job/24750747187

I'm surprised because I have a project with setup python v5 and checkout v4 and it works fine.

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/runner/work/lambdaction/lambdaction/helloworld/.chalice/config.json'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
RuntimeError: Unable to load the project config file. Are you sure this is a chalice project?

You should your question with the complete github action workflow and also the complete log of the action's execution, not just the error, also the step where it failed, so that we have the whole context.

I wanted to know if there are any errors in the code shown in the article that I follow.

Yes, the actions versions are outdated.

https://github.com/shantanuo/lambdaction

So now there's another error, the actions versions are fine, but there's an unrelated error from Chalice. You seem to be missing some configuration, try to commit to your projet the .chalice folder that you should have generated when runnning the "chalice new-project helloworld" command.

An error occurred (SignatureDoesNotMatch) when calling the GetRole operation: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.

Maybe the key has expired, retry the step "Add your AWS credentials to your computer" from the article

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Yes. You are correct. The key has expired. Accepted and upvoted. Thanks for your guidance.
